# How may i customise all UITextField appearances for borderWidth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, calayer, appearance

i am trying to customise all UITextField appearances for borderWith.

Trying something like this.
Only first 2 lines are making a difference.
Rest of the lines not working ?

```
[[UITextField appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UITextField appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[UITextField appearance].layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
[UITextField appearance].layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[UITextField appearance].layer.borderWidth = 3.f;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the appearance proxy doesn't work on layers to do what you want you should subclass UITextField and do your customisations in the layoutSubviews method (or in the init)

Answer (score 5):

You can apply this to a class extended from `UITextField` or any `UIControl` you like to style.

#### 1. Created an `extension` of `UITextField` and added following code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{

    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
}
```

#### 2.1 Create `UITextField` inside Code

Now if you create a `UITextField` inside your code, `#import` the extension of your `UITextField` and create the `UITextField`.

#### 2.2 Create UITextField in `Interface Builder`

If you create the `UIButton` inside the `Interface Builder`, select the `UITextField`, go to the `Identity Inspector` and add the created `extension` as `class` for the `UITextField`.