# How to apply styles to all text fields in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to apply these border styles to all text fields in my view controller. It seems crazy to apply this style to all text fields separately. Is there an easy way to reference all text fields, or should I create some sort of a style class?

```
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    textField.layer.borderColor = (UIColor .grayColor()).CGColor;
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tron5000 say you can use extension like that:

```
extension UITextField {
    func setPreferences() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        // etc.
    }
}
```

And then you can collect all your textfields to one array and iterate over them:

```
var myTextFields = [UITextField]()

func setColorsAndBorders() {
    myTextFields = [tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4] // etc

    for item in myTextFields {
        item.setPreferences()
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example, how does that code know what "tf1", "tf2", etc. are referring to? Where do you set that identifier?

Comment: Nice... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to subclass or write an extension for UITextField. See this page:

[How may i customise all UITextField appearances for borderWidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403970/how-may-i-customise-all-uitextfield-appearances-for-borderwidth)